# use request in Python to submit a form and read the response back

Tags: forms, python-3.x, request

I am trying to submit a form using Python's Request.

When I look at the page source the form looks like this:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="nav-search" action="/">
<input type="search" value="" name="s" class="topSearch" placeholder="Enter Keyword" required="required" autocomplete="off"/>
<ul class="search-suggestions"></ul>
</form>
```

I think it is possible to submit this form automatically using Python and read the response back, but I am not sure how to do it.

My question is:
Is the information in the `form` that I copied above enough to do this? If it is enough then how can I do that in Python 3? If not what else do I need to know before I can use request to do this task?

My other question by just looking at the form is: shall I use `request.get` as opposed to `request.post` for this because in the form above it says: `method="get"`?

Comment: Have you looked at an example of the post request sent by the browser when submitting that same form? You can use that as a blueprint to emulate it using the requests library.

Comment: No I haven't how can I do that?

Comment: Depending on your browser, you should be able to right click on the page and click "Inspect" or something along the same lines. There's typically a network tab that allows you to look at requests sent by certain actions on a page. I would recommend researching that and familiarizing yourself with how webpages behave. It will help immensely in what you are trying to do.

Comment: I did that, but there are about 150 requests, how can I narrow it down?

Comment: Perform the action several times and determine which requests happen multiple times. Continue to narrow it down until you find the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do this through python requests, only looking at the form is not enough. Sometime it requires extra information (csrf token) to be posted.

Open chrome inspect/network, clear the old record, manually submit a form and check the **Form data in 'Request Method: POST'** (usually the first action), see what kind of information it is asking. Then you can pass them in through python request.

Comment: I cannot find anything that resembles Request method: post. After opening inspect/network in chrome, when I enter a keyword, let's say it is `YYY`, then when I search for YYY, then when I look at data under XHR or even ALL in chrome and type YYY in the filter section I do not see YYY in any of the actions.

Comment: @TJ1 can you post the url of the webpage? so I can take a look